# Count all the values in SQL and return 0 if does not have any count

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select State, City, Count(Student) as StudentCount
from Table1
where (State = 'Uttar Pradesh' 
       and City in ('Noida', 'Lucknow', 'Agra', 'Kanpur', 'Greater Noida'))
group by State, City
```

For example, I need the count of the student and also want to include all the cities which don't have any students.

I need the below output

```
State           City           StudentCount
---------------------------------------------
Uttar Pradesh   Noida            20
Uttar Pradesh   Lucknow          30
Uttar Pradesh   Agra              0
Uttar Pradesh   Kanpur            0
Uttar Pradesh   Greater Noida    40
```

but I'm currently getting

```
State           City           StudentCount
-------------------------------------------
Uttar Pradesh   Noida            20
Uttar Pradesh   Lucknow          30
Uttar Pradesh   Greater Noida    40
```

It is skipping the two rows which do not have any count.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your query needs a group by?

Comment: If you don't have a `city` for `Agra`, then it won't show up in your final results like you are querying it.

Comment: If you want all cities to show up even with no records in table1, you need a separate table of cities to join to.

Comment: What type of SQL?

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: SQL Server
Query is : 
Select State,City,Count(Student) as StudentCount
from Table1
where (State = 'Uttar Pradesh' and City in ('Noida','Lucknow','Agra','Kanpur','Greater Noida'))
group by State,City

Comment: You shouldn't have city and state as text in your table, as this is prone to errors (typos, such as Acra instead of Agra or cities not matching the state). Have a state and a cities table instead that you link to. After all, this is called a relational database, so build some relations.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start with a list of the cities you want to count over. Then you can `LEFT JOIN` that to your actual data to aggregate it. When you query and filter by the state, you will eliminate the rows that don't have any records for a city. You want to keep those.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=147d6d6cf823d30b139458cbb220cc94

**SETUP**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (state varchar(20), city varchar(20), studentID int) ;
>
> INSERT INTO table1 (state, city, studentID)
> VALUES 
>     ('Uttar Pradesh','Noida',1)
>   , ('Uttar Pradesh','Noida',2)
>   , ('Uttar Pradesh','Noida',3)
>   , ('Uttar Pradesh','Lucknow',4)
>   , ('Uttar Pradesh','Lucknow',5)
>   , ('Uttar Pradesh','Greater Noida ',6)
>   , ('Uttar Pradesh','Greater Noida ',7)
>   , ('Uttar Pradesh','Greater Noida ',8)
>   , ('Uttar Pradesh','Greater Noida ',9)
> ;
> GO
> ```

**QUERY** Using a CTE.

> ```
> ; WITH cities AS (
>   SELECT 'Uttar Pradesh' AS state, 'Noida' AS city UNION ALL
>   SELECT 'Uttar Pradesh' AS state, 'Lucknow' UNION ALL
>   SELECT 'Uttar Pradesh' AS state, 'Agra' UNION ALL
>   SELECT 'Uttar Pradesh' AS state, 'Kanpur' UNION ALL
>   SELECT 'Uttar Pradesh' AS state, 'Greater Noida'
> )
> SELECT table1.State, cities.city, count(table1.studentID) AS thecount
> FROM cities 
> LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON cities.city = table1.city
>     AND table1.State = 'Uttar Pradesh'
> GROUP BY cities.city, table1.State
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> State         | city          | thecount
> :------------ | :------------ | -------:
> Uttar Pradesh | Noida         |        3
> Uttar Pradesh | Lucknow       |        2
> null          | Agra          |        0
> null          | Kanpur        |        0
> Uttar Pradesh | Greater Noida |        4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=147d6d6cf823d30b139458cbb220cc94)*

Comment: NOTE: I just noticed in my `cities` CTE that I also included a `state`. This was originally intended for stronger specificity in the `JOIN` (`AND cities.state = table1.state`), but I removed it to make the `JOIN` shorter. If you have `cities` with the same name in multiple `state`s, you'll want to add that to the `JOIN`.

Comment: And my query results show why `WHERE table1.state = 'Uttar Pradesh'` is being filtered out of the original results. `JOIN` conditions and `WHERE` filters can dramatically change the final results.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `cte` you can directly express it as :

```
select t1.State, t.City, count(t1.Student) as Student
from ( values ('Noida'), ('Lucknow'), ('Agra'), 
              ('Kanpur'), ('Greater Noida') 
     ) t(City) left join 
     Table1 t1
     on t1.city = t.city and t1.State = 'Uttar Pradesh'
group by t1.State, t.City
```